# Midnight Commander on Windows

Tags: windows, cygwin, console, midnight-commander

I would like to use Midnight Commander on Windows. I found some threads related to `Cygwin` enabling me to use linux software on Windows. Can anyone point me to a documentation that might help me getting started?

Thanks!

Comment: Why specifically Midnight Commander, and not something Windows-native such as [Far Manager](https://www.farmanager.com/screenshots.php?l=en)?

Comment: Oh, didn't know that existed. Post your comment as answer and I'll approve it :) Thank you!

Comment: Far Manager paired with [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) is just awesome! Two open source programs kicking it.

Comment: If you are on Windows 10, you probably want to use WSL instead of Cygwin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install Midnight Commander via Cygwin, follow the standard instructions – [starting with setup.exe](https://cygwin.com/install.html) *(edit: fixed link)* – and make sure to select the `mc` package. I'm not sure whether it works conveniently enough; Cygwin as a whole is somewhat of its own world.

Within Windows 10, you could also install MC through the "Windows subsystem for Linux" using regular `apt install` or `dnf install`. While that's even more isolated from the main system, it still has access to Windows files of course.

Anyway, there is generally very little reason to do so. Midnight Commander isn't unique in its functions (in fact it was originally a clone of the MS-DOS "Norton Commander"), and there exist native Windows programs which do the same thing.

You should instead check out the Wikipedia lists of [NC-inspired software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton_Commander#Norton_Commander-inspired_software) and [other dual-pane file managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton_Commander#Norton_Commander-inspired_software). A common choice for text-console is [Far Manager](https://www.farmanager.com/index.php?l=en), which is a fully native Win32 program but still has the same original NC look & feel. Others (TotalCmd, Salamander, etc.) tend to be fully graphical.

Answer (score 1):

Native Midnight Commander for win32

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mcwin32/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I read this now and I think that to someone else can be useful.

After install mc package, open with an editor /usr/libexec/mc/mc-wrapper.sh and change the line (3rd)

```
/usr/bin/mc P "$MC_PWD_FILE" "$@"
```

with

```
/usr/bin/mc.exe P "$MC_PWD_FILE" "$@"
```

Bert

Answer (score 0):

There is FAR Manager which is essentially the same (and better) https://www.farmanager.com/

I wish they had FAR for linux